# Windows CryptoApi private key dialog box NOT at front

Tags: c#, certificate, itext, cryptoapi

I have a C# background desktop app (like a service) listening http requests.

When I request my service, the service try sign a pdf* using a certificate (local user) that was imported with enabled secure protection of the private key therefore windows prompt a windows Crypto Api dialog box to ask the private key.

*The dialogbox is opened at this like:
MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, pks, new[] { certificate }, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
where MakeSignature is part of iTextSharp.text.pdf.security Version=5.5.0.0

**The problem is that the first prompt of the CryptoApi private key it appears at the background of current window (browser).**

Does someone knows how could I force the cryptoApi to be at the front?

[image: cryptoApi Dialog box]

Best Regards,
Francisco.

Comment: I have the same problem. The dialog appears, but has no focus so it is hidden behind other open windows.